# ::after pseudo element won't be overwritten on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios

I have an anchor tag with two classes:

```
<a href="..." class="class1 class2">...</a>
```

Now I have for both classes a different `::after` element:

I want the after element of `class1` to be overwritten by the after element of `class2` like so:

```css
.class1::after{
content:"3rem after";
font-size:3rem;
}

.class2::after{
content:"2rem after";
font-size:2rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class1">after this one should be a large text</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="class1 class2">after this one should be a small text</a>
```

This works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Edge, but on Safari it won't be overwritten.
Are there any suggestions, why it doesn't work on Safari?

Comment: works properly on ios safari

Comment: Where are you testing this? Are you testing in Safari Windows?

Comment: No, I'm testing on an old iPhone 6 with iOS 12.5.5